# When deleting email from Exchange Mailbox connection is lost to server

Tags: windows-7, exchange-2003, outlook-2003

This is a strange one, even for me.

I have a number of mailboxes setup on Exchange 2003 which I access from the same Outlook instance. Oddly only one has this issue.

Basically when I go to do an operation on one or more emails in the mailbox, on a delete it will happen in every case, for some reason it seems like there is a bottleneck and the connection to the server is stalled/lost until Exchange catches up to what it is that I want to do.

It's odd as it does not happen with the other mailboxes, which are setup in the exact same way, and any operation on those is almost instant.

Basically, this mailbox is the 'support@' mailbox and I simply delete mails once I have noted, read them.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Vick Vega's answer was useful it didn't really help me narrow down the issue. It could even be a physical file fragmentation issue, in the database file or the VM storage file.

It is an odd one, I'm going to recreate the mailbox and see if that resolves it. Regardless I am moving to Exchange 2010 so hopefully the problem will be rectified regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Try running mailbox repair:

```
New-MailboxRepairRequest -Mailbox "mailboxname" -CorruptionType ProvisionedFolder,SearchFolder,AggregateCounts,Folderview -Archive
```

You might need to remove the "-Archive" setting, in case you don't have archive turned on.

Comment: Where do I run this command? I might be mistaken but is this not a PowerShell or Exchange 2007+ command? I am running Exchange 2003.

Comment: My apologies, misread the Exchange version, in order to repair database you would need to run isinteg and eseutil. Both those utilities will require the database to be in dismount state and users will not be able to access it. The pace of those utilities is around 8-10GB/h. Isinteg (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182081) fixes and the eseutil (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192185) used to defrag the DB. 
This might be a good article to follow:

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/exchange-isinteg-eseutil.html

Comment: Thanks but I should of mentioned I have already done this, I did a complete check and rebuild. I also forgot to mention that all the 'other' mailboxes, including the support mailbox, are added to my main mailbox using 'Advanced > Open Additional Mailboxes' features. I hadn't figured that this was an issue since there are 15 mailboxes added in this manner and it only happens to the 'support' mailbox.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the event log? If not, increase the logging level for the DB events. Located at the properties of the server object in the Exchange MMC.